# Dual boot Windows 7 and CentOS 7, Windows 7 BOOTMGR is missing

Tags: linux, windows, operating-system, centos7

I was working with windows 7 x64 and now installed centOS 7 x64 by creating a new partition using windows 7 disk manager. After completing the installation on new created partition, on booting windows 7 computer shows a message " BOOTMGR is missing" "press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart", where as CentOS 7 is working fine.

Professional suggestion are required to manage dual boot. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Appreciated your comments. 
This is a System Programming issue, as OS itself a program. So I ask a question of about two different programs.

Comment: @comsian: I do not think it is a programming issue. Well it might be a programming issue if you are developing uefi bios for the machine or boot loader. But I guess it is not the case.

Answer (score -2):

```
yum install epel-release
yum install ntfs-3g

mount -ro ntfs-3g /dev/sda5 /mnt

Add following entry in /boot/grub2/grub.cfg

menuentry "Windows 7" {
   set root='(hd0,1)'
   chainloader +1
}
```

That's it.